# Como transformar uma string num objeto?

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte *String*:

```
$exp = "(10-9)+(7-6)";
```

Vamos supor que eu processe essa *String* e consiga retornar o seguinte resultado, no formato *String*:

```
$exp = "new Expressao(
    new Expressao(new Numero(10),new Operador('-'),new Numero(9)),
    new Operador('+'),
    new Expressao(new Numero(7), new Operador('-'),new Numero(6))
)";
```

Como faço para criar dinamicamente um objeto `Expressao` como indicado na *String*?

Comment: Tu quer fazer um parse em php eh?

Comment: @fernandoandrade estou fazendo uma função que recebe uma expressao numerica e transforma ela num objeto. Consegui tratar a string e monta-la como preciso, mas o resultado é uma string nao consigo executa-la. Eu quero executar o que está nessa string e assim criar um objeto expressao() com os atributos informados

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assim como o Tiago Luz respondeu, o `eval` serviria bem no teu caso, já que está tratando a string para receber apenas caracteres permitidos e acredito que você mesmo cria a string com os objetos, certo?

Um exemplo com o `eval` ficaria mais ou menos assim.

```
<?php
class Expressao {
    private $val;
    private $nu1;
    private $nu2;
    private $ope;
    function __construct($nu1, $ope, $nu2) {
        $this->nu1 = $nu1;
        $this->ope = $ope;
        $this->nu2 = $nu2;
    }
};
class Numero {
    private $val;
    function __construct($val) {$this->val = $val;}
};
class Operador {
    private $val;
    function __construct($val) {$this->val = $val;}
};
$exp = "new Expressao(
    new Expressao(new Numero(10),new Operador('-'),new Numero(9)),
    new Operador('+'),
    new Expressao(new Numero(7), new Operador('-'),new Numero(6))
)";

$r = eval('return ('.$exp.');');

var_dump($r);
```

Note que eu concateno um `return` com a expressão, isso é para que a variável `$r` receba o resultado da expressão e não apenas que ela seja executada. É como se o `eval` jogasse teu código dentro de uma função e executasse, então pra receber algo dessa função você precisa dar um `return`.

Espero que tenha ficado claro.

Eu ainda recomendo que você faça todo esse *parser* na classe `Expressao`, algo como

```
$exp = new Expressao('(10-9)+(7-6)');
```

E ali dentro você crie uma função que trate a string `"(10-9)+(7-6)"` e transforme ela nos teus objetos.

---

Você também consegue criar objetos "dinâmicos", por exemplo:

```
function getObj($val) {
    if (in_array($val, explode('', '(+-)'))) {
        $class = 'Operador'; 
    } else if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $val) > 0) {
        $class = 'Numero';
    } else return null;

    return new $class($val);
}
```

<sub>Porém não estou com tempo no momento para elaborar esse código ↑</sub>

Comment: Exatamente o que eu estava procurando

Comment: Legal! Não tinha visto sua resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso com a função `eval($code)` do php.

O que estiver em `$code` será executado como se fosse código PHP. Cuidado com possíveis brechas de segurança!

[Neste link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.eval.php) está a explicação.

Comment: Já estava imaginando que seria eval(), porém não sei como utilizar essa função. Não há um exemplo no referido link que ajude a resolver o meu problema

Comment: No código há uma função que sanitiza a entrada string permitindo apenas números e  ( -  + ) acredito que não há maiores riscos com eval() de qualquer maneira é apenas um exercício de OO

Comment: A função eval($bla) executa o código php que está na variável $bla, como se ele estivesse escrito no seu script. Exemplo: eval("echo 'oi';");

Comment: Tiago Luz, você poderia formular uma respota, por que não consigo realizar a referida operação com eval(). Recebo a mensagem de erro: `eval()'d code on line 1`

Answer (score 0):

A titulo de curiosidade

Pesquisando consegui achar uma forma de fazer com o que `eval()` crie o objeto tal como queria utilizando um closure

```
public function criaObjeto($obj){
        eval("\$newObj = function(){return $obj;};");
        return $newObj();
}
```

Não tenho total domínio sobre como trabalhar com `eval()` para afirmar se não gera uma falha de segurança.

No meu código coloquei uma função que sanitiza a entrada de dados permitindo apenas `caracteres numéricos`, `(` , `)` , `+` e `-`.

```
class Validacao{
    private function limpaString($obj){
        return preg_replace("/[^0-9\+\-\(\)]/", "", $obj);
    }
}
```

Contudo não tenho total certeza no que toca a segurança

Answer (score -2):

O adequado seria você fazer dessa forma:

```
$ExpressaoObj->new Expressao();
```

Só que teu codigo está bem confuso e com erros!